# Is it possible to create a cross-browser AJAX photo uploader with a progressbar?

Tags: javascript, upload

I've been searching around and round the web on how to do this.

It seems almost impossible??

Is it possible to create a cross-browser AJAX photo uploader with a progressbar? Dynamic thumbnail generation I can do, but I can't seem to find a cross browser solution for pure-javascript dynamic upload with progressbar that will work on IE and other browsers.

Any tips guys? :/

Comment: *Anything* is posible with enough work -- but I think you'll want a framework.

Comment: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: You are probably better off going for something that uses flash like uploadify if you want to be cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using this http://www.uploadify.com/ with html 5 fallback.

Comment: They can't be used in commercial applications? What does that mean?

Comment: On their site.. :S

The main points subject to the terms of the License are:

Source Code cannot be used in commercial applications;
Source Code cannot be redistributed; and
Source Code can be modified to create derivative works.
No claim of suitability, guarantee, or any warranty whatsoever is provided. The software is provided “as-is”.
The Article(s) accompanying the Work may not be distributed or republished without the Author’s consent

Comment: They are saying you can't take the **source code** and resell it.  You are free you use it as intended in commercial or non- apps.

Comment: Hi...are you using any services call for the data fetch? if yes then i have solution...